# Simple Form For is not updating changes in collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

Unable to update the changes/delete/adds of languages in simple_form_for collection

I have looked through Stackoverflow, GitHub, the Simple Form documentation. I also have tried to reset the database on rails to no avail on the terminal.

Also, when adding another language to the collection, the file is saved and the localhost and heroku host does not reflect the new language being added. I even committed my code and pushed to Github to merge successfully to ensure the languages are added. It still shows the old version of the collection.

### `ruby on rails - ruby version 2.5.5`

```
<div class="editgif">
<%= simple_form_for(@gif) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :title, required: true, autofocus: true %>
<%= f.input :language, collection: ["Select Language", "All Sign Languages", "American Sign Language", "Argentine Sign Language"] %>
```

---

Localhost and Heroku are not able to update these changes. It still shows the old version even though the new code does have new additions.

Comment: I think you are checking on the wrong page.

Comment: did you test the code in local after the merge? also did you pushed the code in Heroku? and restarted the server?

Comment: Hello Vishal - thanks! I am still struggling to find an answer as to why my collection will not update.
Ravi - I have pushed it both on local and Heroku - still same issue - the collection will not update. Thanks for double checking!